# Add KPI indicator for every item in a list automatically

Tags: list

I have a list with two columns. How can I add a KPI indicator for each new item created automatically? Where the value column is one, and the target column is the other?

Can I define the KPI list to do that? Is it possible using a workflow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Create a basic custom list with columns:

- Value (type: Number)
- Target (type: Number)
- KPI (type: Calculated. Data type returned from this formula is: Number)

Formula for the calculated column is:

```
=IF(Value>Target,"<img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF'","<img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF'")
```

This will render a nice KPI icon in the KPI column.

(I'd recommend this simple solution because the SP KPI list has had sorting issues at least in SP2007/SP2010 and is a bit heavy if you only need to show a KPI icon based on two columns)

Answer (score 0):

There are some good tutorials on creating KPI`s. You should be able to do the things you want with this.

[Here](http://pravahaminfo.blogspot.com/2011/05/creating-status-indicatorskpi-in.html) is the first blog.

A [blog](http://localgovernmentsharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/creating-a-kpi-list-based-on-a-sharepoint-list/) by Rob Ashcroft.

Microsoft`s articles [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/getting-started-with-sharepoint-status-indicators-HA010380634.aspx) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-publish-key-performance-indicators-kpis-HA010080027.aspx#BM2).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard list then you can also do it with XSL - there is a post on creating a dashboard from a list on my [blog](http://paylord.wordpress.com) which is similar to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Add below formula in calculated column field to show status indicator based on your column value

```
="<DIV style='font-weight:bold;  line-height:50%; align-center;font-size:36px; color:"&CHOOSE(LEFT([your column value],1),"gray","green","orange","red")&";'>•</DIV>"
```